# How to update the background of a div with an array value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm having difficulty updating the background of a div in both javascript and jquery.

html

```
<div id="images">
<img class="mypics" src="kitty.png" style="display:none"></div>
<img class="mypics" src="doggy.png" style="display:none"></div>
<img class="mypics" src="mouse.png" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

javascript / jquery

```
picArray = document.getElementsByClassName("mypics");
$('#images').css('background-image', 'url("' + picArray [0].src + '")');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below syntax

```
$('#images').css('background-image', 'url(' + picArray[0].src + ')');
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to change **single div backgtound**? Use `querySelector`

```js
const picArray = document.querySelector(".mypics");
$(picArray).css('background-image', 'url("' + picArray [0].src + '")');
```

**Multi div?**

`getElementsByClassName` is `HTMLCollection`

```js
const picArray = document.getElementsByClassName("mypics");
picArray.forEach(pic => {
    $(pic).css('background-image', 'url("' + picArray [0].src + '")');
});
```

Also you can use `#images` children

```js
consr images = document.getElementById("images").children;

Array.from(images).forEach(pic => {
    $(pic).css('background-image', 'url("' + picArray [0].src + '")');
});
```

**Notice: Use `Array.from` because `children` is `array-like`**